# access to observer object VUE/Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem in VUE.

```
console.log(p.id)
console.warn(this.$store.state.product.productList)
console.log(this.$store.state.product.productList[p.id])
```

This return me this values

[image]

I use the p.id to filter from the productList in my store an specific element (the one you can see in the console warn), but on the third consele.log instead of return me the object I have an undefined value and I don´t know why.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how your productList look like? If is array of objects you probably need `this.$store.state.product.productList.find(v => v.id == p.id)`

Comment: state {
    product {
        buyProduct:undefined
        productList:Object
            13362059:Object
            2565507:{
               signed:false
               freeDelivery:true
               idStatus:-1
            }
       }
}
By the way, after trying your first approach
The console.warn now is undefined
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Comment: you have object in object so if your p.id is 2565507 its wrong because parent object is 13362059, check the id value

Comment: no, each id is independent object inside productList. And each id contain the info of the products that I have in the page (with the parameters of signed, freeDelivery and id Status among others). Sorry for the misunderstood.